# returning nested state with redux and thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm fairly new to redux & thunk, and have been following tutorials to try and understand, and am managing to work it into my app ok. One thing i'm not understanding, is how i can get several state objects on the root level into one nested object. For example, right now my state looks like:

```
{
  timeline: [Array] // My timeline data in an array of objects
  timelineHasErrored: false,
  timelineIsLoading: false
}
```

But what I really want is:

```
{
  timeline : {
    data: [Array] // My timeline data in an array of objects
    hasErrored: false,
    isLoading: false
  }
}
```

and i'm really not quite sure how to nest these, or what the proper way to do that is. Below is my redux code, it's pretty simple so i'll post it all.

**Reducers index**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { timeline, timelineHasErrored, timelineIsLoading } from './timeline'

export default combineReducers({
    timeline, timelineHasErrored, timelineIsLoading
});
```

**Timeline Reducers**

```
import { TIMELINE_HAS_ERRORED, TIMELINE_IS_LOADING, TIMELINE_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS } from '../constants/action-types.js'

export function timelineHasErrored(state = false, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TIMELINE_HAS_ERRORED:
      return action.hasErrored;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function timelineIsLoading(state = false, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TIMELINE_IS_LOADING:
      return action.isLoading;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function timeline(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TIMELINE_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS:
      return action.timeline;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Actions**

```
import { TIMELINE_HAS_ERRORED, TIMELINE_IS_LOADING, TIMELINE_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS } from '../constants/action-types.js'
import api from '../services/api'

export function timelineHasErrored(bool) {
  return {
    type : TIMELINE_HAS_ERRORED,
    hasErrored : bool
  }
}

export function timelineIsLoading(bool) {
  return {
    type : TIMELINE_IS_LOADING,
    isLoading : bool
  }
}

export function timelineFetchDataSuccess(timeline) {
  return {
    type : TIMELINE_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS,
    timeline
  }
}

export function timelineFetchData() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch( timelineIsLoading(true) )

    api.getTracks().then(
      res => {
        dispatch( timelineIsLoading(false) )
        dispatch( timelineFetchDataSuccess(res.body) )
      },
      err => {
        dispatch( timelineIsLoading(false) )
        dispatch( timelineHasErrored(true) )
      }
    )
  }
}
```

And then in my react component I format the object like how i want it... but i think it would be better to have it nested in the actual state so i'm not creating extra work for myself if things change

```
// Redux State
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {    
  const obj = {
    timeline : {
      data : state.timeline,
      hasErrored: state.tracksHasErrored,
      isLoading: state.tracksIsLoading
    }
  }

  return obj
}

// Redux Dispatch
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchData: () => dispatch( timelineFetchData() )
  }
}
```

If anybody has any tips or corrections for me bring em on, i'm trying to get a solid grasp on redux, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your timeline reducer is pretty small, so you could have it as a single reducer as follows:

```
const initialState = {
    data: [],
    hasErrored: false,
    isLoading: false
};

export function timeline(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TIMELINE_HAS_ERRORED:
      return {
         ...state,
         hasErrored: action.hasErrored
      };

    case TIMELINE_IS_LOADING:
      return {
         ...state,
         isLoading: action.isLoading
      };

    case TIMELINE_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS:
      return {
         ...state,
         data: action.timeline
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Then you wouldn't need to call `combineReducers()`, unless you had other reducers.

Comment: ahh i see, so one function and you just replace the applicable object based on the action.type called. I will have many more reducers though, so could i still keep my reducer index the same? I would just be exporting `timeline`? instead of the 2 i have now?

Comment: Yeah you would just export your single `timeline` reducer, and in your root reducer (if you have one) you would `combineReducers()` your `timeline` and any other reducers